# Не работает login. Django

Tags: python, django

Авторизация работает только для админа (и обычная, и через админку). Для любого другого пользователя, для которого точно прошла регистрация, не находится соответствий пароля и логина, хотя они точно правильные
Авторизация стандартная (функция login)

Comment: Выполняли ли миграцию БД после подключения системы авторизации? И вообще нужно больше информации, без конкретики можно долго тыкать пальцем в небо.

Answer (score 1):

Их туда и не должно пускать. Для того чтобы в админку пускало других пользователей, надо им указывать `is_staf = True`

```
user_object.is_staf = True
user_object.save()
```